# app.use() and router.post() is not working

Tags: node.js

My app.use() is not working.It shows 'Cannot POST /student_register'.
Its working only if I give app.post() and router.use(),And my validationError is also not working.Is there any other methid where I can make the express-json-validator work.
Here is the code

```
**app.js**
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
const student_register = require('./routes/student_register');
app.use('/student_register',student_register);
app.listen(3000);

**student_register**
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const router = express.Router();
app.use(express.static('public'))
const Student = require('../services/Student-info/studentRegister');
const Student_Register = require('../model/studentRegister');
const validate_student = require('../routes/validation_schemas/student_register');
var { Validator, ValidationError } = require('express-json-validator-middleware');

var validator = new Validator({allErrors: true});

var validate = validator.validate;


router.post('/student_register',validate({body: validate_student}),(request,response,next) => {
    
    
    var mailid = request.body.mail;
    var student_name = request.body.id;
    var student_password = request.body.password;
    Student_Register.where({email:mailid}).fetch({require:true})
        .then(() => {
            response.json({code : 400 ,status : "Failed" ,message : "Already Present"})
        })
        .catch(() => {
            
                bcrypt.hash(student_password,10,(err,hash) => {
                    Student.s_register(mailid,student_name,hash)
                    response.json({code : 400 ,status : "Success" ,message : "Inserted Successfully"})
                })
            
        })
})


app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log("Coming")
    if (err instanceof JSONSchemaValidationError) {
        res.status(400).send('invalid');
        next();
    }
    else next(err); 
});
module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Of course, If you are trying to make a `view` function for the route `/student_register` which handles `POST` request you have to use `app.POST` or `router.POST`. Generally, `app.use` or `router.use` is used for `middlewares`.

Comment: If is give router.post() it is not working.Still the same issue

Comment: Change `router.post('/student_register'` to `router.post('/'`. If you are using the former, your endpoint will be `/student_register/student_register`.

Comment: I got it..it worked..THANK YOU SO MUCH :)